# Escape $("html").ajaxError() in one of the $.ajax() call

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling

```
$("html").ajaxError(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError){
  //show proper message based on error.
});
```

I'm also sending JavaScript errors to server using `$.ajax()` from catch block and from `window.onerror` function. In case those two calls fail, I don't want it to come to above ajaxError handler.

Comment: Can you explain your problem better?  It isn't clear what the issue is.

Comment: [@Tim](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9786422/148271) has understood it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error handler will catch all exceptions thrown by jQuery's ajax functions. If you don't want it to handle an exception, I would suggest inspecting the URL of the ajax request to see if it is to your JS Error handling script, and if so, ignore it.

```
$("html").ajaxError(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError){
    if (ajaxSettings.url.substring(0,len)=='http://www.example.com/logJSError') {
        return;
    }
});
```